Dark mode for Chinese @ SE?
I was looking over Winter Bash 2020 on the Stack Exchange site. I noticed the following hat and requirement:

Flashlight.
Try Dark Mode

When you click about this hat the description says:

Have Dark Mode enabled and visit a page on Stack Overflow in English, Japanese, Portuguese, Russian, or Spanish.

If you go to your user preferences on Stack Overflow under theme you can choose dark. It should look something like this:



It looks like this function is only available on Stack Overflow. But, I'm assuming this is something that could later roll out on all @ SE sites.
What does Chinese @ SE think? Is this something we would like?

At the moment, it is questionable whether Dark Mode will be rolled out to the rest of the network at all. From the announcement post:

Future releases
At this point, the focus of Dark Mode is on Stack Overflow and we’ll eventually bring it to MSO. While the retheming we did across the network two years ago makes updating our [styles] easier, creating dark versions of all of our sites, particularly the custom-designed ones, is going to be a huge challenge we’re not able to contemplate at this time. The artwork on some of those sites simply can’t be made dark because we don’t have access to the original art files and, to be honest, some of the themes will always be better as-is.

Now, sites without a custom design like Chinese.SE will probably be easier to convert to Dark Mode (I've even seen one of the Community Managers, Catija, mentioning this, but I can't find it) but I wouldn't get my hopes up.
